# Crazy Large Render Needed for Exhibition

Tags: resolution

My company needs a Blender scene rendered at 338700px by 164550px for a backdrop for an exhibition stand. Blender is telling me that the maximum I could render the image is at 65536px by 65536px, but I'm not sure whether this resolution is a limitation of Blender or my work PC.

Is it even possible to render such at 338700px by 164550px? If so, does anyone know  a render farm who could do it on my Company's behalf?

The exhibition is next month so any timely assistance would be most appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Matthew Shepherd

Comment: 65536 is the largest number that can be coded in 16 bits. It's a limitation of Blender, not your computer. Maybe you could use several cameras, do each render separately, then stitch them in another software ?

Comment: As I haven't had to do this in Blender, I'm not fully qualified, but the first instinct is to go for rendering in tiles, using Camera > Shift to move between them, (not altering the perspective from that of the fixed viewing point). Then reassembling the tiles at whichever point  further down the pipeline can handle the data. Maybe someone who's actually done this can give a watertight answer.

Comment: Do you really need such a high resolution ? It's 28 m width at 300 dpi ! Maybe that chart will help http://resources.printhandbook.com/pages/viewing-distance-dpi.php

Comment: PS.. you can key-frame 'Shift', so you could set the render up as a single job.

Comment: What size the print should have in reality?